# Could it be correct to say "near from"?

Tags: grammar

Can you tell me please if this sentence is grammatically correct:

> My school is near from my house.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to tell what you mean, but it's not correct and will sound strange to a native speaker. Typically in English we say *near to* or *close to* and *far (away) from*.

Comment: I'll add that, like the use of many prepositions, this is not predictable or explainable: it is just the way English is, and learners of English just have to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use *near*, the *to* is not needed:

> The school is near my house.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how close you mean, you could also use

> near by
>   The school is near *by* my house.

which has a *closer* meaning, e.g. across the street, than

> The school is near *to* my house.

which can mean in your neighborhood.

Comment: Native English speakers don't speak like that. Just use "near." "Near to" is just as awkward as "near from."